# Alternative of "end" attritube in Aura:Iteration for LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

Can anyone tell what is the alternative of **"end"** attribute in **aura:iteration** for LWC. for example

Aura

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.records}" var="rec" end="{!v.loadLimiter.limit}">


</aura:iteration>
```

What i understand is "end" will let display no of records . **The index of the collection to stop at (exclusive)**

What is the alternative for this in LWC . like in lwc we have

```
<template for:each={records} for:item="rec">


</template>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's no such thing in LWC. Just use a second list to display pages, as in my [example app](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/T8W4TOI0iu4t3bB6biR8/src/app.css). They likely did not include this in LWC because it could have relatively poor performance as opposed to building your own pagination. If you look at my code, you'll see that this is efficiently handled with slice:

```
  get currentPage() {
    return this.filteredResults.slice(
      (this.pageNumber - 1) * this.pageSize,
      this.pageNumber * this.pageSize
    ).map((name,index)=>({ key: index, name }));
  }
```

Given how trivial it is to implement your own version of this algorithm, it's not entirely surprising they didn't include `for:start` and `for:end` or some such. Of course, if you're outside Salesforce, you could easily implement your own [directives](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.reference_directives), if you wanted a project of your own to have this built-in.